# Integration of a 3D matrix over one direction

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-integration

Want to integrate a 3D matrix of size `n*m*p` (`n` rows, `m` columns and `p` slices) numerically using the Trapez rule over the third dimension, i.e., over the slices direction, in MATLAB without using any loops.

Following is my attempt, for an integrand function `f(i,j,x) = cos(i+j+x)`, from `x = 0` to `pi`:

```
i = 1:3;
j = 1:4;
x = 0:0.1:3.14;
[I,J,X] = ndgrid(i,j,x);
INTEGRAND = cos(I+J+X)
INTEGRAL = trapz(x, INTEGRAND(:,:,X));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate over the third dimension using `trapz` you need to specify the dimension of integration as the third argument.

From the [MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) page for `trapz`:

```
Q = trapz(Y)
Q = trapz(X,Y)
Q = trapz(___,dim)
```

You will need to use something like:

```
INTEGRAL = trapz(x, INTEGRAND, 3);
```